# How do I write a search query using Kohana PHP?

Tags: php, kohana

I have a table (`product_shoppingcart`) with 4 columns :

```
id, product_id, shoppingcart_id, product_quantity.
```

I'm using Kohana's ORM.

I want to write a search query which returns all the rows where the `shoppingcart_id` column contains 1 (for example).

I already tried:

```
$arr = ORM::factory('product_shoppingcart')->where('shoppingcart_id',$shoppingcartID)->find_all();
```

but that doesn't work.

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: What doesn't work about about that? I just set it up as you wrote and I was able to get it to work. I suspect your model maybe using 'has_one' or some other attribute. Could you post your model as well?

Comment: Also, do you have a profiler attached to your controller? That way you can see the SQL that is run. You could try running the query in phpMyAdmin to see the raw results.

Comment: Ambirex,
it works but it only returns one row, not many of them. i want to get maybe 10 rows whose shoppingcart_id is equal to $shoppingcartID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code should work, but perhaps the problem is that you're not iterating over your result set?

```
$results = ORM::factory('product_shoppingcart')
           ->where('shoppingcart_id', $shoppingcartID)
           ->find_all();
foreach ($results as $product_shoppingcart) {
  print Kohana::debug($product_shoppingcart->as_array());
}
```

If you have more than one row with that id, this should give you a result iterator in $results, which you then walk with the foreach loop.  I have lots of examples of similar working code, if you're still not able to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what it would look like:

```
$arr = ORM::factory('product_shoppingcart')->where(
                    'shoppingcart_id',"=",$shoppingcartID)->find_all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt your table be "product_shoppingcarts" or am I missing something?

Comment: You can set $table_name = 'product_shoppingcart'; within the model if your table is named something else.